# Insert query crashes?

Tags: php, insert, blob

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$title = $_REQUEST['TitleFieldToAdd'];
$thread = $_REQUEST['ThreadFieldToAdd'];
$file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);
$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][0];
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][0];
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if(!$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DBFORTEST'))
{
    printf("Connecting To DB Has Failed. Error Msg: %s", mysql_error($link)); exit;
}
$query = "INSERT INTO  `DBFORTEST`.`News` (`id`, `title`, `thread`, `imageContent`, `imageName`, `imageType`, `imageSize`, `date')
          VALUES (NULL ,  '$title',  '$thread', '$file_content', '$file_name', '$file_type', '$file_size', '$date');";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
echo("SUCCEEDED");
}else
{
    echo("FAILED");
}
?>
```

I could create a query with blob information to insert... but it doesn't work :(
It seems like mysqli_query() crashes but I cannot find a reason why this is happening.
Is this because the query is way too long?   Because of blob image info?

Comment: I would recommend using `mysqli_error()` to obtain the error description, if your query fails. You already do it for connecting...why not for the query?

Comment: I just tried and it still doesn't tell me why it crashes :(...  and sorry about missing ' up there. In the code, I have it. I made a mistake when posting it up here.

Comment: Ohhhh, now I found it. the syntax of the mysql version im using was different. That's what the error is about. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try not to use mysql keywords as column names. eg 'date' here
2. there is syntax error in your query :

   `thread`, `imageContent`, `imageName`, `imageType`, `imageSize`, `date'

should be with ` instead of '

```
 `thread`, `imageContent`, `imageName`, `imageType`, `imageSize`, `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed ` of `` `date) `` ?

You can use `mysqli_error($link)` to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the missing `'`  in `'date) VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

try to change into query:

```
`date
```

with

```
`date`
```